# win32 controls: different coordinates in resource.rc and CreateWindow?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating a small win32 application. Currently I have 6 text labels coded in the resource file, like this:

```
IDD_MAIN DIALOGEX 0, 0, 465, 279
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "SpiderPigOverseer"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "sample text",IDC_STATIC1,"Static",SS_SIMPLE | WS_GROUP,344,70,33,8
    [...]
END
```

But I want to access these in a for loop so I thought I would create them dynamically(?) with this code:

```
IRValues[i] = CreateWindow("static", "sample text", SS_SIMPLE | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 344, 70+10*i, 33, 8, hDlg, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

But, this makes the text bigger. The x and y-position are much less then the ones created with resource file and the width and height also seems to differ. Why is this?

EDIT: I tried using the following code to convert, but couldn't get it to match exactly.

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
TEXTMETRIC tm;
GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
cxAveChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
cyAveChar = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;
ReleaseDC( hWnd, hdc );
```

Comment: You don't need to create them, use `GetDlgItem`.

Comment: What @purecuteness says: you don't need to create the windows yourself just so you can use them in a for loop. You can give them all ids and use GetDlgItem, or even do a loop with GetWindow() with GW_CHILD/GW_HWNDNEXT to iterate over them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Coordinates in .rc files represented as *Dialog units* which  are not equal to pixels. It is made for automatically adjust controls size depending on system font size.
You can convert dialog units to pixels as follows:

```
pixelX = MulDiv(templateunitX, LOWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits()), 4);
pixelY = MulDiv(templateunitY, HIWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits()), 8);
```

Or simply use `MapDialogRect()`

Comment: How can I make the text in the default font size? I have some labels created in the resource file which doesn't need dynamic creation. Should I change the dynamic xy-coors with trial and error?

Comment: I don't understand what you want =) If you want to access your labels created in .rc you should use `GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC1)`. If you want to create labels you should use `CreateWindow`, if you also want them use default font, you should `SendMessage(hLabel, WM_SETFONT, GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), 0)`

Comment: [GetDialogBaseUnits is a bit of a crock](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040217-00/?p=40573/).